# How to stop RewriteEngine/PHP redirect loop?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The task seems very simple:

all requests must be passed through one file.

However,

when following code is added to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

and following code is added to /index.php:

```
if( isset($_GET["route"]) && $_GET["route"] != "/index.php" ){
header("Location: ".$_GET["route"]);
}
```

then it causes redirect loop!

Causes for example such loop:

*www.site.com/image.jpg -> (redirected by httpd.conf)*

*www.site.com/index.php?route=/image.jpg -> (redirected by index.php)*

*www.site.com/image.jpg -> (redirected by httpd.conf)*

*www.site.com/index.php?route=/image.jpg -> (redirected by index.php)*

...

So, the question is following:

**How to stop this loop?**

To stop for example in such way:

*www.site.com/image.jpg -> (redirected by httpd.conf)*

*www.site.com/index.php?route=/image.jpg -> (redirected by index.php)*

*www.site.com/image.jpg (no further redirection)*

Comment: Exactly what do you want to accomplish with this rewriting/redirecting scheme? That will help to find a solution.

Comment: @amarnasan it is written in the start of message - all requests must be passed through one file (which perform some additional operations before start of native processing request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit of patch, but I think it works.

httpd.conf:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)a=a$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET["route"]) && $_GET["route"] != "/index.php" ){
    header("Location: ".$_GET["route"].'?a=a');
}
```

The thing is: First time the rewrite engine redirects the page to `index.php`. Then, in `index.php` there's a redirection to the same file but adding parameter `a=a`. Then rewrite engine comes again, but he has orders of not redirect when found the string `a=a` in the query string, and there's no further redirection.

Of course this will end in a 404 error, since you're filtering only non-existant files with the first two `rewritecond`, but I guess you know how to deal with that.

Comment: **Works exactly as expected! Thanks a lot for the solution!**

Answer (score 1):

Your rule looks fine but `R=301` is a bit odd in your rule as you don't want to expose your internal URL in browser.

However PHP code is looking suspect due to this condition:

```
$_GET["route"] != "/index.php"
```

Which will always be `true` since `/index.php` itself will not be routed through this rule due to these conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

Hence your code will cause a redirect loop by continuously redirecting using `header` function.

I suggest keep your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And your PHP code should just check presence of `$_GET['route']` but should not do any redirects.

Answer (score 0):

First, put this to .htaccess file, not in httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Then, remove this redirect from your index.php file. You can get all your variables via $_GET or $_REQUEST.

Comment: First: "permitting .htaccess files causes a performance hit" (apache manual). Then: RewriteEngine rewrites mentioned variables.

Comment: @user3119308 Sure, it will. But if you're dealing with only one .htaccess file, you will never notice this performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

What a senseless solutions. Of course it will cause redirect loop. In the RewriteCond-s you trying to catch files and dirs names that not exists in the server file system, and then you trying to pass their names to the index.php in which you make to request them again, again and again.

Comment: If there are no such RewriteCond-s, then it does not solve the problem. So, this is not a solution. Moreover, in this case $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME] does not shows, what file is really requested (after redirection by DirectoryIndex command).

Comment: The problem is not in yours RewriteCond itself but in the sending header 302 in yours  /index.php with not exists file or dir name, which cause of the triggering rewrite rules again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single boilerplate that may come in handy, it should be placed on the top, after RewriteEngine on condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^[\s/]*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

An env was added, it works by theory, however I have tested it only once, see if it can solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is good solution in some other case, but not in this case, because it avoid redirecting at all, but in this case one redirecting (to index.php and back) still is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you putting this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

In httpd.conf? You need to place this into file called **.htaccess**, create it into your root directory.

Comment: And what if he wants to put it in httpd.conf ?

Comment: @konstantin-rachev "permitting .htaccess files causes a performance hit" (apache manual)

Comment: And is that a solution? Permitting a performance hit? Stopping the loop by going faster?

Comment: @amarnasan Is that a solution? Putting to .htaccess? This does not stop a loop.

Comment: I'm not the one who suggested that solution. I'm the one who said IT IS NOT A SOLUTION.